# SED to remove a Line with REGEX Pattern

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

i've got a hundreds of files with thousands of lines, which i need to delete some lines that follows a pattern,so i went to SED with regex .The struct of files is something like this

```
A,12121212121212,foo,bar,lorem
C,32JL,JL
C,32JL,JL
C,32JL,JL
C,32JL,JL
A,21212121212121,foo,bar,lorem
C,32JL,JL
C,32JL,JL
C,32JL,JL
A,9999,88888,77777
```

I need to delete All the lines that starts with "**A**" and ends with "**lorem**"

Expected output-

```
C,32JL,JL
C,32JL,JL
C,32JL,JL
C,32JL,JL
C,32JL,JL
C,32JL,JL
C,32JL,JL
A,9999,88888,77777
```

I've made the Regex :

```
^(A).*(lorem)
```

And it match in my text editor (Sublime,UltraEdit)

In the UNIX shell

```
sed '/^(A).*(lorem)/d' file.txt
```

But somehow it doesn't work,it shows the whole file, and i can't figure out why.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: In `sed` the parens are being treated as literal characters.  If you want them to be for grouping you need to escape them, but you don't seem to need grouping for this regex so just get rid of them this time

Comment: I understand now friend,thanks for your help

Comment: you can also use `grep -vx 'A.*lorem' file.txt`

Comment: @Sundeep thanks friend

Comment: Note that you can also use a field approach with awk: `awk -F, '$1!="A"||$NF!="lorem"'`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$ sed '/^A.*lorem$/d' file.txt
```

- `^A`: starts with an `A`
- `.*`: stuff in the middle
- `lorem$`: ends with `lorem`

Answer (score 23):

The others gave you correct solutions but didn't explain why your regex didn't work. The `()` surely were useless, but if you had used the regex with other tools/languages, you might very well have had the expected result.

It didn't work with `sed` because it will by default use [POSIX's basic regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html), where the characters for grouping are `\(` and `\)`, while `(` and `)` will match literal characters. There were no such brackets in your input text, so it didn't match.

Your regular expression would have worked if you had used GNU's `sed -r` or BSD's `sed -E`, the flag switching to POSIX's extended regular expressions where `(` and `)` are used to group and `\(` `\)` match the literal brackets.

In conclusion, the following commands will do the same thing :

- `sed '/^A.*lorem$/d' file.txt`
- `sed -r '/^(A).*(lorem)$/d' file.txt` (with GNU sed)
- `sed -E '/^(A).*(lorem)$/d' file.txt` (with BSD sed and modern GNU sed)
- `sed '/^\(A\).*\(lorem\)$/d' file.txt`

Comment: can also add that some sed versions use `-E` rather than `-r`

Comment: Thanks, I always forgot GNU isn't everything. Edited !

Answer (score 1):

Remove the brackets.

Using your code, the appropriate one-liner becomes-

```
sed '/^A.*lorem/d' file.txt
```

If you want to be more rigourous, you can look at James's answer which more correctly terminates the regex as-

```
sed '/^A.*lorem$/d' file.txt
```

Both will work.

Comment: use `{}` editing button or select the lines which contain code and press `Ctrl+k`... that way you would get syntax highlighting...

Comment: @Sundeep, that's what I usually do for longer passages. But for this one liner I just went with the back ticks (`). Thanks for the info!

Comment: Thanks for the help